# How To Create Generic Templates for CreateView and UpdateView in Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I have quite a few models in my django project, and I'm trying to avoid having to create an html template for all of them. I'm trying to create a number of views that use the same template.

For example, I have an email model:

```
class Email(models.Model):

EMAIL_TYPE = (
    ('work', 'work'),
    ('home', 'home'),
    ('other', 'other')
)

id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
owner = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='email_set')
address = models.EmailField()
primary = models.NullBooleanField(help_text='Is this the primary email address you use?')
type = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=EMAIL_TYPE, null=True, blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.address

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('people_and_property:email-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

Then I have the view:

```
class EmailCreate(PermissionRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    """
    This view allows staff to create email objects
    """
    model = Email
    fields = ['owner', 'address', 'primary']
    template_name = 'people_and_property/generic_create.html'
    permission_required = 'people_and_property.can_add_email'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        """
        This should add in the url for the template to send the data to.
        """
        context = super(EmailCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['name_of_object'] = 'Email' # This tells the template what it is that we're editing
        context['action_link'] = 'people_and_property:email-create'
        return context
```

Then the template:

```
{% extends "case_manager/employee-portal-base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<h2>Edit {{ name_of_object }}</h2>

<div class="form">
    {% autoescape off %}
    <form action="{% url {{ action_link }} %}" method="POST">
    {% endautoescape %}
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_ul }}
    <BR>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Changes"/>
    </form>
</div>


{% endblock %}
```

What I would like to do is repeatedly create simple views like this, pass in the form action url to tell which view will process the form data, and just use the same template over and over.

I tried to pass in a variable (action_url) into the context, but it will not render the template correctly. I've also tried to pass the full html for the form in as a variable in the context, but that hasn't worked either. I've turned autoescape off for those parts of the template.

I'm sure it's something simple, but I can't quite figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use the `{{}}` inside the tag, since you're already in "code", as it were. This works fine:

```
<form action="{% url action_link %}" method="POST">
```

But also note that you are simply posting the form back to the URL that rendered it anyway, so you can just skip the whole creation of action_link and just use the "." signifier:

```
<form action="." method="POST">
```

Answer (score 1):

[`reverse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) the url in your view, get the full url to the action and then pass that url to the template.

`{{}}` won't work like that inside `{% %}`

So do this in the view:

```
context['action_link'] = reverse('people_and_property:email-create')
```

And in the template:

```
<form action="{{ action_link }}" method="POST">
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks!